# Two-tone spectrogram

Tags: plotting, color, signal-processing

The default spectrogram command uses a single color and appears to just vary the saturation of the color to express intensity. So, for example, in the default implementation which looks like this:

[image]

its sort of a yellow which is darkened or lightened according to intensity.

I would rather have a bi-tone graphic in which there are two colors, say red and blue, and the intensity is continuous scale going from dark blue (low) to dark red (high). How can I do this?

Comment: Use the  option `ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Blue, Red}, #] &)`?

Comment: or do e.g. `Spectrogram[ExampleData[{"Sound", "Apollo13Problem"}], ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors"]`

Comment: Right, ThermometerColors is the right idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on J.M.'s comment, the solution is to use a ColorFunction, Spectrogram[ExampleData[{"Sound", "Apollo13Problem"}], 
 ColorFunction -> "LightTemperatureMap"]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can play with custom interactive selection (see definition of `f` below):

```
Manipulate[f[(Blend[{c1, c2}, #] &)], {c1, Blue}, {c2, Red}]
```

[image]

Generally, selecting a color scheme is an artsy process, dependent on how you data vary along the color gradient. Check out [ColorSchemes](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ColorSchemes.html) for builtin variety. You can also reverse them as for example "RedBlueTones" is inverse of your scale but you can use

```
ColorData[{"RedBlueTones", "Reverse"}]
```

Let's compare. Define a test function:

```
f[c_] := Spectrogram[ExampleData[{"Audio", "DogBark"}], ColorFunction -> c]
```

Apply to some cases:

```
f/@{
ColorData[{"RedBlueTones","Reverse"}],ColorData[{"CandyColors","Reverse"}],
"ThermometerColors",ColorData[{"BrownCyanTones","Reverse"}],
"Rainbow","DarkRainbow",
"TemperatureMap","LightTemperatureMap",
(Blend[{Blue,Red},#]&),(Blend[{Cyan,Pink},#]&),
(Blend[{Darker@Blue,Lighter@Red},#]&),(Blend[{Lighter@Blue,Darker@Red},#]&)}
```

[image]